# JMeter Beanshell Get Text File Size Save to Variable

Tags: jmeter, filesize, filewriter, beanshell

In Beanshell Post Processor I am creating a file and writing variable data received from a JDBC request to that file. I need to capture the file size of the created text file in KB and save to a variable so that I can call in a subsequent JDBC request.

[image: Create File]

[image: Use FileSize in JDBC request variable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should stop using Beanshell for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and switch to [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).
2. [Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables inside scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as they might resolve into something causing compilation failure or unexpected behavior or will be resolved only once.
3. You can save the size of the file into a JMeter Variable as:

   ```
   vars.put("fileSize", String.valueOf(new File("/path/to/file").length().toString()));
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To know file length in KB, use [length()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()) method:

```
long fileSizeInKB =  new File("fileName").length() / 1024;
```

> The length, in bytes, of the file

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't  return any value in the variable using Beanshell.

Comment: @user2642587 write it at the end of script with the valid file name